# Confused about memory holes

Tags: ram, osdev, bios

*I'm trying to make a small 64-bit kernel (x86), and i recently found out about memory holes, but even after googling for a while i couldn't find all the answers i wanted.*

If i understand it correctly, some parts of the RAM are unavailable for use because they are used by something else (BIOS, memory mapped devices, etc.) these are so called "memory holes".

I have a few questions about them:

- **do i have to worry about memory holes after switching to long mode (64-bit mode)?** for example i can reclaim the BIOS memory areas, since i won't be needing the BIOS anymore, but what about the other memory holes?
- if i still have to worry about memory holes, is there a safe area above which there definetly won't be any memory holes? That is, can i simply not use any the first, say, 16 MiB or memory and be sure that there are **no memory holes above 16 MiB?** (i don't mind sacrificing 16 MiB when i still have another 8 GB or so more)

I know there exist some BIOS functions that allow you to go through the memory map as a list, but i would rather not have to deal with having to sort that list aswell as dealing with overlapping regions.

Comment: AFAIU long mode shouldn't affect physical memory layout.  physical RAM will be mapped at somewhat arbitrary addresses due interleaving the address space with (memory mapped) devices, so, e.g., if you have "16GiB of RAM" some of that will almost certainly appear above address 0x400000000.  you really want to be using the e820 BIOS call early on to figure out which parts of your address space are usable.  e.g. this is almost the first thing printed when Linux boots

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_(x86) might help as well